# Find minimum integer such that any integer \in [1, n] can be constructed from its consequent subsums

Tags: summation, integers, integer-partitions

For example, here's (SPOILERS) breakdown for $1143$, which is the solution for $n = 9$

1. $\underline{1}143$
2. $\underline{11}43$
3. $114\underline{3}$
4. $11\underline{4}3$
5. $1\underline{14}3$
6. $\underline{114}3$
7. $11\underline{43}$
8. $1\underline{143}$
9. $\underline{1143}$

The questions are:

- are there more *anomalies* like $18$, what are they?
- are most solutions like that: $111 \dots some\ digits\ within \pm1$?

Those digits at the tail seem to grow and they cannot be more than $9$

#### Appendix A: Brute-force solution in JavaScript

```
function partialSums(numbers) {
  let sum = 0;
  const result = [0];
  for (const number of numbers) {
    result.push(sum += number);
  }
  return result;
}

function solve(maxSum) {
  for (let n = 1; true; n++) {
    const s = n.toString();
    // simple shortcut for speed up
    if (s.includes('0')) continue;
    const digits = s.split('').map(Number);
    const sums = new Set();
    const partials = partialSums(digits);
    for (let start = 0; start < digits.length; start++) {
      for (let end = start + 1; end <= digits.length; end++) {
        const subSum = partials[end] - partials[start];
        // sum will only increase further in the inner loop
        // so we can just break from it
        if (subSum > maxSum) break;
        sums.add(subSum);
        if (sums.size === maxSum) return n;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Appendix B: Brute-force results (More SPOILERS)

$$\begin {array} {r|r} \ n & solution\\
\hline
1 & 1 \\
2 & 11 \\
3 & 12 \\
4 & 112 \\
5 & 113 \\
6 & 132 \\
7 & 1114 \\
8 & 1133 \\
9 & 1143 \\
10 & 11134 \\
11 & 11144 \\
12 & 11154 \\
13 & 11443 \\
14 & 111155 \\
15 & 111165 \\
16 & 111544 \\
17 & 111554 \\
18 & 256318 \\
19 & 1111555 \\
20 & 1111655 \\
21 & 1111665 \\
22 & 1115554 \\
23 & 1194332 \\
24 & 11111766 \\
25 & 11111776 \\
26 & 11116565 \\
27 & 11116665 \\
28 & 12337741 \\
29 & 12377441 \\
30 & 111116766 \\
\end {array}$$

Comment: https://oeis.org/A296447

Comment: and OEIS answers one question: $a(59) = 213388888552$

Comment: Shame on me, I should have tried to search in OEIS

Comment: @almagest BTW there's a mistake on their site. They say "the latter being the second term of the sequence not to start with 1; a(59) = 213388888552" and reference a table with a(51) also starting not from 1. Actually, it's exactly a(59) with one 8 removed

Comment: @kirilloid You should let them know. See [here](https://oeis.org/Submit.html)